# How to create an iterator for an aliased projection of select?

Tags: java, sqljdbc, sqlj

When you have a query like this:

```
select A,B from MYTABLE where C='1'
```

you just declare the following:

```
#sql iterator Cursor(String A, String B);
```

But what if you have a query like this one?

```
select T1.A, T1.B from MYTABLE T1 where C='1'
```

Comment: i think same should work as `cursor()` is bothered about type of data not whether alias is used or not .

Comment: sadly it appears not :(